# kinetic.js: how to find and remove shapes

Tags: kineticjs

I'm pretty new to kinetic.js library and I need some help to better understand how it works.
My need is to draw 3 shapes (rectangles) named 'first' , 'second' and 'first' (again):

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});
var diceLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    fill: 'yellow',
    name: 'first'
});
diceLayer.add(rect);
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    fill: 'red',
    name: 'second'
});
diceLayer.add(rect);
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 20,
    y: 20,
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    fill: 'green',
    name: 'first'
})
diceLayer.add(rect);
stage.add(diceLayer);
```

Then to select the two shapes named 'first', scale them @ 50% and fill with another color

```
var selectionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
selectionLayer = stage.find( '.first' );
selectionLayer.stroke('1px');
selectionLayer.scaleX('0.5');
selectionLayer.scaleY('0.5');
selectionLayer.fill('silver');
selectionLayer.draw();
```

Such syntax, as far as I see maintains the original shape (and that's exaclty what i need) and duplicate shapes modifying the copied objects setting a stroke, scaling them, ...
But then, how can I delete the objects created by previous find/selection?

I've tried both .clear() and .remove() but they does not seem to work.

```
selectionLayer.clear();
selectionLayer.remove();
```

What's wrong?

Stefano

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code.

**Note:** You can find and remove the shapes by using javascript variables like **stage, diceLayer, rect** .

**Your Code:**
var selectionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

Your above code is not working. Because **selectionLayer** child value will be empty when we initialize a object.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body
        {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        #buttons
        {
            position: absolute;
            left: 10px;
            top: 100px;
        }
        button
        {
            margin-top: 10px;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="LoadFunction()">
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v5.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer">

        function LoadFunction() {

            var stage, diceLayer, rect1, rect2, rect3;
            stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: 'container',
                width: 100,
                height: 100
            });
            diceLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            rect1 = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: 0,
                y: 0,
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                fill: 'yellow',
                name: 'first'
            });
            diceLayer.add(rect1);
            rect2 = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: 10,
                y: 10,
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                fill: 'red',
                name: 'second'
            });
            diceLayer.add(rect2);
            rect3 = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: 20,
                y: 20,
                width: 20,
                height: 20,
                fill: 'green',
                name: 'first'
            })
            diceLayer.add(rect3);
            stage.add(diceLayer);


            document.getElementById("change").addEventListener("click", function () {                
                for (var i = 0; i < stage.get(".first").length; i++) {
                    stage.get(".first")[i].stroke('1px');
                    stage.get(".first")[i].scaleX('0.5');
                    stage.get(".first")[i].scaleY('0.5');
                    stage.get(".first")[i].fill('silver');
                }
                diceLayer.draw();
            }, false);
            document.getElementById("remove").addEventListener("click", function () {
                var selectionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

                diceLayer.remove();
            }, false);
        }
    </script>
    <div id="buttons">
        <input id="change" type="button" value="Change" />
        <input id="remove" type="button" value="Remove" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the problem that I have is that at the end I have to draw a matrix of 100x100 rect shapes each of them identified by an unque name (or id) and when the user click on "Highlight" checkbox an ajax call to an external script would get me back a list of shapes to be highlighted. On other hands my purpose is to copy (or clone?) some rect on the whole reticule, highlight them (with a stroke, different fill color or whatelse) and then when user un-check the same checkbox the application must switch back to previous status (basically showing and hiding the selection on every click on checkbox).

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem (and so highlight a restricted set of of the entire population available) I've...

1. Defined a new Layer

   ```
   var selectionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
   ```
2. Get the list of rect to be highlited (with a jquery ajax call) and then create a new rect object (with same position of returned one by find statement) but different border, color and whatelse in order to add it at the end as new Layer on stage container:

   ```
   $.get( "/map/get-text-probed-dice.php", function( data ) {
       selectedDice = stage.find( data );
       selectedDice.each(function(shape) {
           var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
               x: shape.x(),
               y: shape.y(),
               width: shape.width(),
               height: shape.height(),
               stroke: 3
           });
           selectionLayer.add(rect);
       });
       stage.add(selectionLayer);
   });
   ```
3. Then when user ask hide selection, the same selection layer can be removed

   ```
   selectionLayer.remove();
   ```

Most probably there was a smarter way to approach it, but I'm definitively a newbie and that's the smartest approach I've found.

Ciao,
Stefano